# making a XMLHttpRequest change the parameter when send the request, with header and "+" as parameter

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Wondering why the request is replacing the parameter just at sending the request (send() method) by ":", this is the way the request is being send, thanks in advance.

`var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();`

`oReq.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')`

`let p1 = "+";`

`oReq.send(p1);`

[see the form data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbfQl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not really `:`, if you click "view source", you'll see that it's a `+`. But since `+` is interpreted as a space in URLs, and since URL encoded form data consists of key-value pairs, you have a space parameter with no value.

You need to properly encode your "+":

```js
let p1 = encodeURIComponent("+");

console.log(p1); // %2B
```

[image]

> Note: the `:` is not sent to the server, it's just Chrome displaying your keys and values